# jQuery JTable paging not working

Tags: jquery, json, pagination, paging, jquery-jtable

I'm having trouble with jQuery Jtable pagination.

JSON response:

```
{
    "Result": "OK",
    "Records": [
        {
            etc...
        }
    ],
    "TotalRecordCount": 33
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#foo').jtable({
    title: 'My Table Title',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 25,
    actions: {
        listAction... etc
    },
    fields: {
        title: myTitle,
        etc
    }
});
```

I used variables for every fields parameters:

```
var myTitle = {
    title: 'MyTitle',
    type: 'text'
};
```

which are all declared before the jtable instance.

The table works fine, but shows all 33 records instead of 1-25 of 33.
In the http header, I can see the Query String Parameters set correctly:

```
Query String Parameters
    action: list
    jtStartIndex: 0
    jtPageSize: 25
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your sql statement is like, but I was having the same issue you were and finally figured out that you have to set the paging yourself, using `LIMIT` in MySQL (it's a bit more complicated in MSSQL).

```
--MySQL, PHP
"SELECT * FROM Students ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT" . $_REQUEST['jtStartIndex'] .
"," . $_REQUEST['jtPageSize'];

--SQL Server, ASP
"SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name ASC) AS Row, * FROM Students)
    AS StudentsWithRowNumbers
WHERE Row > " & Request.QueryString("jtStartIndex") & " AND Row <= " &
Request.QueryString("jtPageSize")
```

[jTable Paging (source)](http://www.jtable.org/demo/pagingandsorting)

Comment: Yup that's exactly it. I wasn't doing anything with the paging parameters.

Comment: Yeah, it took me awhile to figure that out. They never say anything about having to do that, except at the end of that page...